# Trying to parse table data into csv file. Is there a way to parse dynamic genrated table data in a row in csv with BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of names and trying to parse whole table content in a row of a with `Xpath`. In some name if there is less content my `webdriver` crushed and programs stops, So I decided parse table with `pandas`. I did my research to parse table with pandas into csv file. But don't know how to implement it. 
here is the link of table I am trying to parse in a row in csv

```
DLLC , ACT , OREGON , 11-25-2015 , 11-25-2017 , PPB , PRINCIPAL PLACE OF BUSINESS , 22325 SW MURPHY ST,BEAVERTON , OR   and so on.
```

see every data field from that table will be look like this in excel in each cell. I don't want any header. I just table data in row.
Now I have list of names in csv something like this:

```
HALF MOON BEND FARM, LLC
NICELY GROWN LLC
COPR INCORPORATED
so on......
```

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")
#time.sleep(5)

username = driver.find_element_by_name("p_name")
#time.sleep(1)
username.send_keys("xxxxxxx")
#username.clear()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[6]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input").click()

entity= driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("xxxxxxx")


entity.click()
html = driver.page_source



Registry_nbr =       driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text
Entity_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").text
Entity_status = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]").text
Registry_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]").text
#Next_renewal_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]").text
entity_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]").text


Ttest=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table[32]/tbody/tr/td[2]").text


with open("sos.csv", "w") as scoreFile:
    scoreFileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile)
  scoreFileWriter.writerow([Registry_nbr,Entity_type,Entity_status,Registry_date,entity_name],)

scoreFile.close()

soup =BeautifulSoup(html)



for tag in soup.find_all('table'):
    print tag.text
```

Comment: have you tried opencorporates? they may have already captured your data in a structured format, and they have an open API. your sample LLC is on there, https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_or/116457094

Comment: @joshi123 I searched few names on opencorporates . I didn't get any  information. Do you have Any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this after `entity.click()`

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
words = soup.find_all("td")
table_data =  soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')

word = list()
for cell in words:
        a.append((cell.text).encode('utf-8'))

with open('name.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(word)
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the html you can parse it using BeautifulSoup and find the table you want. Looking at the HTML page you reference, I do not see any classid's or identifying keys to search for so just indexing in to table[2] will have to do.

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

NBSP = u'\xa0'
tables = [ [ map(lambda d: d.text.replace(NBSP, u''), r.findAll('td'))
           for r in t.findAll('tr') ]
         for t in soup.findAll('table') ]

business_entity_data = tables[2]
keys = business_entity_data[0]

with open('page.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys)
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    csvwriter.writerow(dict(zip(keys, business_entity_data[1])))
```

You should end up with a file containing:

```
Registry Nbr,Entity Type,Entity Status,Jurisdiction,Registry Date,Next Renewal Date,Renewal Due?
1164570-94,DLLC,ACT,OREGON,11-25-2015,11-25-2017,
```

Comment: in case I want whole table on that page in a row  ?@MikeRobins

Comment: All the data that is on that page is read into the tables variable. I suggest you try this code and put in some print statements (consider the prettyprint module) to see what is there. tables is a three dimensional array i.e. list of lists of lists. The data on the page is not very regular so you may be better processing it in python rather than csv.

Comment: I used this code and works fine,but only for table. its been 3 days I can't find something good to parse all data in single row plus I don't know how to read my csv file which have all the search query names one by one and get all the data in csv file. @MikeRobins

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not quite understand what you mean by 'parse all data in a single row' and 'all the search query names one by one'? Can you give me an example how you want to use the data from that web page? I'll try to answer again in the morning, its late here.

Comment: lets take your code. can you modify it so it can parse whole table data fields in csv (table showing data of one company.so, all the data must me in row for individual company). I tried by changing table index but I get `index error out of range`. @MikeRobins